# How do I debug Query Notifications on SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sqldependency, query-notifications

I am trying to get query notifications to work, but my application is not receiving any notifications. **How do I debug Query Notifications?**

I am using the code availble here http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/chatter.aspx. I can see that the queues, the services and the stored procedures are being created on the server, but the [OnChange event on my SqlDependency](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldependency.onchange.aspx) object is not being fired.

Can I somehow track the notifications?

Comment: It's worth checking the "Special Considerations Using Query Notifications" on MSDN, since you might be falling foul of one or more of them - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aewzkxxh.aspx - especially worth checking the SQL Agent service account and SET option settings

Answer (score 1):

See [The Mysterious Notification](http://rusanu.com/2006/06/17/the-mysterious-notification/), the troubleshooting tips section.